# Doubt about eigenspace being subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Recently I was studying about eigenvetors and eigenspaces .I saw the following statement:

Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation.
For an eigen value $a$ of T ,
$$V_a := \{v \in V : T(v) = av \}$$
is a subspace which is called the eigenspace associated to $a$.

However any subspace must contain the $\{0\}$ element but this set V
comprises of all the eigen vectors corresponding to the linear transformation T and by definition the null vector is not considered an eigen vector so $\{0\}$ cannot be in V ,hence V(i.e eigenspace) cannot be a subspace .My question is how to solve this contradiction.Am I missing something? Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminology is always confusing :) Let $V$ be any vector space over a field $F$ and let $T:V\to V$ be linear. Here is the definition:

1. For any $a\in F$, we define $V_a:= \ker(T-aI)=\{v\in V\,:\, T(v)=av\}$. We call this the $a$-eigenspace of $T$. (This is equal to the kernel/null space of a linear map hence it is a vector subspace of $V$.)
2. A scalar $a\in F$ is called an eigenvalue of $T$ if the $a$-eigenspace $V_a:=\ker(T-aI)$ defined above is NOT the zero subspace. In this case, a non-zero element of $V_a$ is called an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $a$.

Note that the first definition says nothing about eigenvalues and eigenvectors. It just gives a name to the subspace $\ker(T-aI)$. This subspace can be defined for ANY $a\in F$.

An eigenvalue for $T$ is a special type of scalar, as mentioned in definition 2. It is a scalar for which the subspace $V_a$ is not the zero subspace. Lastly, an eigenvector is defined to be a non-zero element of $V_a$.

You might be confused because the term "eigenspace" interpreted in a purely linguistic sense seems to suggest that it is the space of all eigenvectors. Well, that's not quite true. It also includes the zero vector, which is not considered to be an eigenvector. If you look at the definitions carefully, you'll see there is no contradiction, it's only that you seem to attach extra meaning to the terms than is present in the definitions.

Comment: Thank you now this seems fairly clear!

Answer (score 1):

A vector $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $a$ if and only if $v\ne0$ and $v\in V_a$. We add $0$ to the set of eigenvectors with eigenvalue $a$ in order that $V_a$ becomes a subspace, but nobody is claiming that *every* element of $V_a$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you for explaining!